# Using ngAside for opening a simple left-menu Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

I just want to test opening a left modal with the help of ngAside used at the following Repository:

> https://github.com/dbtek/angular-aside

I think I am doing it right, still can find a js error. Can someone help?

***index.html:***

```
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Required CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <!-- Required Scripts --> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-aside.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/> 
    {{name}}

    <script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAside']);
    //Controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

        $scope.name = "Peter";

        var asideInstance = $aside.open({
          templateUrl: 'aside.html',
          controller: 'AsideCtrl',
          placement: 'left',
          size: 'lg'
        });

    });

    app.controller('AsideCtrl',function($scope){


    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

***aside.html***

```
Hello World!
```

***ERROR:***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `aside` service, you have to inject it like this (notice the $aside injection in the constructor) :

```
 app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $aside){
...
    });
```